# Show that $W=R(A)\oplus R(T)=N(A)\oplus N(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem;
Let $W$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. Also assume for $A: W\to W$, $T: W\to W$, that $W=R(A)+R(T)=N(A)+N(T)$

Question;

If the proof is wrong, how should I instead go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that $x\in R(A)\cap R(T)$ iff $x \in N(A)\cap N(T)$, but I can't see how you derived that.

To solve the problem, notice that $\dim W=\dim N(A)+\dim N(T) - \dim N(A)\cap N(T)$, thus:
\begin{align}
\dim N(A) + \dim N(T)&= \dim W + \dim N(A)\cap N(T) &(1)
\end{align}

Notice the following:

\begin{align*}
\dim W &= \dim R(A)+\dim R(T) - \dim R(A)\cap R(T)\\
&=(\dim W - \dim N(A)) + (\dim W - \dim N(T)) - \dim R(A)\cap R(T)\\
&=2\dim W - (\dim N(A)+\dim N(T))-\dim R(A)\cap R(T). & (2)
\end{align*}

Now replace $(1)$ in $(2)$ and you'll be able to conclude that $\dim N(A)\cap N(T)=\dim R(A)\cap R(T)=0$.